# Manufacturing yield and probability

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution, conditional-probability

I need some suggestions to how calculate the yields for a silicon process. I'll try to give you an idea of the problem i'm facing.

Basically the manufacturing yield is the ratio between the number of faultless chip and the number of chip created. Usually to have a prediction of this value it is used the Poisson distribuction. Basically I want to find the probability that a chip with an area of $A$ has no defect :

$Y = P(k=0) = \frac{\lambda^k \cdot e^{-\lambda}}{k!} = e^{-\lambda}$

with $\lambda = A \cdot D_0$  ( $D_0$ is the average number of defect )

Let's make the example I have 2 different subsystems inside my device, So the area of my device is $A_{device} = A_1 + A_2$. It's easy to see that the yields of the device is :

$Y_{device} = P_{device}(k=0) = e^{-\lambda_{device}} = e^{-A_{device}\cdot D_0} = e^{D_0 \cdot (A_1 + A_2)} = P_1(k=0) \cdot P_2(k=0) = Y_1 \cdot Y_2$

Now let's say I'm able to handle one defect because I've redundancy in my chip. This means I can accept one defect ( for example ). This means my yields should be something like :

$Y = P(k \leqslant 1) = P(k=0) + P(k=1) = (\lambda + 1 )\cdot e^{-\lambda}$

If I take the previous example it's easy to see the yield of the device is not the multiplication of the single yields of the subsystems anymore. I can see pretty clearly from a mathematical point of view but I can't see it from a probability point of view.

$P_1(k \leqslant 1) = (A_{1}\cdot D_0 + 1 )\cdot e^{-A_{1}\cdot D_0} = P_1(k=0) \cdot (A_{1}\cdot D_0 + 1 )$

$P_2(k \leqslant 1) = (A_{2}\cdot D_0 + 1 )\cdot e^{-A_{2}\cdot D_0}= P_2(k=0) \cdot (A_{2}\cdot D_0 + 1 )$

$P_{device}(k \leqslant 1) = (A_{device}\cdot D_0 + 1 )\cdot e^{-A_{device}\cdot D_0}= P_{device}(k=0) \cdot (A_{device}\cdot D_0 + 1 ) = P_1(k=0) \cdot P_2(k=0) \cdot ((A_{1} + A_{2})\cdot D_0 + 1 ) \ne P_1(k \leqslant 1) \cdot P_2(k \leqslant 1)$

Because I'm calculating the probability for the subsystem 1 to have have at max 1 defect ( so it's basically the probability to work ), then I do the same for the subsystem 2 and then I want to see the probability of subsystem 1 works **and** subsystem 2 works.  Can someone explain this to me ?

Then there is another bigger problem. Let's say the subsystem 1 has redundancy instead the subsystem 2 hasn't, how can I find the probability ( so the manufacturing yield ) that subsystem 1 **and** subsystem 2 work ? The idea was to do the following:

$P_1(k\leqslant 1)$ : probability the subsystem 1 works with no problem ( it cans handle one defect )

$P_2(k = 0)$ : probability the subsystem 2 works with no problem ( it can handle no defect )

$P_{device} = P_1(k\leqslant 1) \cdot P_2(k = 0)$ : manufacturing yield of the chip.

Of course according to what I said before I can't use this way at all. Any idea ?

Sorry for the long post but it was the only way to actually explain properly the problem.